# Parse Json from Google Charts

Tags: jquery, json, google-visualization

I'm using json to load dynamically data into a Google Chart, the chart looks good, but i want to read the json in order to use these values to create a table with the json values.

I read the data with:

```
var formData = {type:"All"};
var jsonDataAll = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data : formData,        
    url: "./content/chartsData.php",
    dataType:"json",
    async: false
}).responseText;
```

This is the response:

```
{
     "cols": [
        {"id":"","label":"Level","pattern":"","type":"string"},
        {"id":"","label":"Number","pattern":"","type":"number"}
      ],
      "rows": [
        {"c":[{"v":"Preschool","f":null},{"v":8,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Kindergarten","f":null},{"v":23,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Elementary","f":null},{"v":32,"f":null}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Junior","f":null},{"v":31,"f":null}]},
      ]
}
```

How can get the values?

```
Preschool - 8
Kindergarten - 23
Elementary - 32
Junior - 31
```

Any ideas?

Comment: All the answers works, the issue is in the array, i have a comma at the end of the last row. `code`   var obj = JSON.parse(jsonDataAll);
  var valuesAll = obj.rows;
   $.each(valuesAll, function(index, value) {
     console.log(valuesAll[index].c[0].v+ - +valuesAll[index].c[1].v);
   });`code`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my shot at the Question. http://jsfiddle.net/7uLk3ktn/

Taking into account the JSON data you have available, here is the (jQuery) code that I have used in order to extract the data.

```
<h1> School data </h1>
<ul id="data">
</ul>

var json_rows = json.rows;
 $.each(json_rows, function(index, value) {
      console.log(json_rows[index].c[1].v);
      var school_name = json_rows[index].c[0].v;
      var school_value = json_rows[index].c[1].v;
      $('ul#data').append('<li>'+ school_name + ' - ' + school_value + '</li>');
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this might get you started:

```
var data = '["Level","Number"]';

for(var i=0; i < obj["rows"].length; i++){
    data += ",[" + obj["rows"][i]["c"][0]["v"] +","+ obj["rows"][i]["c"][1]["v"] + "]";
}
```

Then the data variable can be passed into where you need in the charts part.
I made [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tg1b654s/1/) to mess around with the formatting.

I would definitely suggest checking out the [Google Chart documentation](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart).

Answer (score 1):

You just need to parse the JSON to an object and then iterate through the column and row data stored in the representation to get at the data you need.  That might look something like this:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonDataAll);
// get column labels
var columns = [];
for(i=0; i<=obj.cols.length; i++) {
    columns .push(obj.cols[i].label);
}
console.log(columns); // ['Level','Number']
// get row data
var rows = [];
for(i=0; i<=obj.rows.length; i++) {
    var row = [];
    for(j=0;j<=labels.length;j++) {
        row.push(obj.rows[i].c[j].v);
    }
    rows.push(row); 
}
console.log(rows); // [['Preschool',8],['Kindergarten',23],['Elementary',32],['Junior',31]]
```